# How to add select menu in prestashop?

Tags: menu, prestashop

I have theme, and in `header.tpl`

```
 <div class="nav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <nav>{hook h="displayNav"}</nav>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

But this is normal `<ul>`, `<li>` menu... How to make it responsive - f.e. select menu?

Answer (score 0):

In Prestashop the horizontal top menu is generated by this module "blocktopmenu" in the modules folder you can find blocktopmenu.php and you can edit how the module generate the menu html